# Python permutation with recursion

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm having trouble writing a function to display all of the permutations of a list. Here is my code. The main function is given and I cannot change it. When I ran the code, nothing showed up. What's wrong with my code?

```
def perm(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    l = [] 
    for i in range(len(lst)):
       m = lst[i]
       rem = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
       for p in perm(rem):
           l.append([m] + p)
    return l

def main():
    list = input().split(',')
    start = []
    perm(list)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The input is: `A,B,C`

The expected output is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']

['A', 'C', 'B']

['B', 'A', 'C']

['B', 'C', 'A']

['C', 'A', 'B']

['C', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: If the main function is given, then why does it have a `start` variable which is not passed to the `perm` function? And if you don't print anything anywere, why are you surprised nothing shows up?

Comment: @trincot I don't know. The main function is given like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is fine as far as the permutations go. However, it only returns the list of permutations. It appears, the task as given expects it to print them as well. Just insert right before (or instead of) the return statement:

```
def perm(lst, lvl=0):  # add recursion level as parameter
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    l = [] 
    for i in range(len(lst)):
       m = [lst[i]]
       for p in perm(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:], lvl+1):
           l.append(m + p)
    if lvl == 0:  # only print if it is the top call
        for p in l:
            print(p)
    return l
```

Comment: I insert your code right before the return statement. I get the output like this ['B', 'C']
['C', 'B']
['A', 'C']
['C', 'A']
['A', 'B']
['B', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'C']
['B', 'C', 'A']
['C', 'A', 'B']
['C', 'B', 'A']. If I insert the code instead of the return statement, it showed TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable .

Comment: @user380178 Yeah, you are of course printing from the recursive calls, too. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong with your code. Just need to print the results.

```
def main():
    list = input().split(',')
    print perm(list)
```

A bit of advice: it's a bad idea to use `list` as variable name, since it will alias the built-in type `list`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `print` in your code, which is why you don't have any output. Because your function is recursive, and at deeper recursion levels the list is shorter, you'll only want to print at the outermost level.

It is probably the easiest if you wrap your function in yet another function, and only print in that wrapping function. Rename the original function to something else, and call the outer one `perm`:

```
def perm(lst):
    # The original function, but renamed:
    def recurse(lst):
        print('recurse', lst)
        if len(lst) == 0:
            return []
        if len(lst) == 1:
            return [lst]
        l = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
           m = lst[i]
           rem = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
           for p in recurse(rem): # call the renamed function
               l.append([m] + p)
        return l
    # only print in the wrapping function
    l = recurse(lst)
    print (l)
    return l
```

With some use of list comprehension and moving the `len(lst) == 0` test out of the recursive function, you can rewrite the above to:

```
def perm(lst):
    def recurse(lst):
        if len(lst) == 1:
            return [lst]
        return [[m] + p  for i, m in enumerate(lst) for p in recurse(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:])]

    l = recurse(lst) if len(lst) > 0 else []
    print(l)
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.permutations` for this:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations(['A','B','C']))

[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A')]
```